Why are there $2^{m(n)}$ different internal states?
I am reading these notes. Theorem 2 states:

Suppose that there is a set $D(n)$ of pairwise distinguishable strings for $L$ on inputs of length $n$.
Then any streaming algorithm that recognizes $L$ must use at least $\log_2 D(n)$ bits of memory on inputs of length $n$.

The proof goes as follows:

Suppose, for a contradiction, that there is a streaming algorithm for L that uses $m(n) < \log_2 D(n)$ bits of memory on inputs of length n. Then this algorithm has at most $2^{m(n)} < D(n)$ distinct internal states, so by the pigeonhole principle there must be two different distinguishable strings $x$, $y$ in our set that take the
algorithm into the same state. But this in turn means that the output of the algorithm on inputs $xz$, $yz$ must be the same, which is a contradiction.

I am a little uncertain how the algorithm "has at most $2^{m(n)} < D(n)$ distinct internal states". From what I am calculating: There are $c$ states in the machine. There are $|\Sigma|$ elements for the alphabet. So, there should be $c|\Sigma|^{m(n)}$ different internal states, no? Any clarification on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated, I believe the rest of the proof makes sense to me assuming $2^{m(n)}$ is correct number of internal states.
